# Marketing Cloud Data Views status and documentation

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, documentation, data-views

What is the current status of [Data Views](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/08/22/data-views-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud/) on Salesforce Marketing Cloud?

The official documentation at [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_views.htm&type=5) returns a 404 error.

Is the functionality being phased out? Or is that an error on SF documentation side?

Comment: Indeed, it seems to be a problem with SFMC documentation. The second link you provided is indeed the correct Data Views doc link..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with the entire Salesforce documentation at the moment. I'm sitting next to a Salesforce employee at the moment, who assured me that the responsible team is aware and already on it.

So basically the answer is Data Views exist and won't possibly be retired ;)